# Cursor fastexecutemany error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unicode conversion failed (0) (SQLExecute)')

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am trying to upload several large csv files into a sql server database, using cursor fast_executemany. Below is a sample of the code.

```
  if item.endswith(zip_ext):
      file_name = os.path.abspath(item)
      zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)
      zip_ref.extractall(directory)
      zip_ref.close()
      os.remove(file_name)

for item in os.listdir(directory): # Load and Edit CSV
   if item.endswith(ext):
       df = pd.read_csv(item)
       df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:'InvoiceNo',df.columns[2]:'OrderNo',df.columns[20]:'Syscode',
                          df.columns[27]:'SpotDate',df.columns[28]:'Network',df.columns[30]:'SpotTime',
                          df.columns[29]:'SpotLength',df.columns[31]:'Program',df.columns[32]:'SpotName',
                          df.columns[21]:'Source'},inplace=True)
      
       df['BillDate']='2021-03-01' # Enter Preferred Bill Date Here!
       df['FileName']=str(item)
       df[['SpotDate','BillDate','SpotTime']]=df[['SpotDate','BillDate','SpotTime']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
       df['SpotTime']=df['SpotTime'].dt.time
       df['OrderNo']=df['OrderNo'].apply(lambda x: '' if x == 'NULL' else x)
       df = df[['InvoiceNo', 'OrderNo', 'BillDate', 'Syscode', 'SpotDate', 'Network', 'SpotTime', 'SpotLength',
               'Program', 'SpotName', 'Source', 'FileName']]
       
# Connect to SQL Server
       conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;'
                             'SERVER=PWDBS006SQL;' #UPDATED 2/4/21
                             'DATABASE=Marketing Cross-Channel Affidavits;'
                             'Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                             autocommit=True)
       crsr = conn.cursor()
       crsr.fast_executemany = False
       
# Insert Df to SQL
       sql_statement = '''INSERT INTO dbo.SpectrumReach_Marketing (InvoiceNo, OrderNo, BillDate, Syscode, SpotDate,
                        Network, SpotTime, SpotLength, Program, SpotName, Source, FileName)
                        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'''
       list_of_tuples = list(df.itertuples(index=False))
       crsr.executemany(sql_statement, list_of_tuples)
       
       crsr.close()
       conn.close()
```

When running this code I get the error message: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unicode conversion failed (0) (SQLExecute)').

I have used this code for several large datasets from a few sources, that should be formatted exactly the same, and it has worked, but for a specific vendor it breaks and shows the above error. Additionally this code runs when I have fast_executemany = False, but due to the size of the files I am attempting to transfer, it is not feasible to have the data uploaded that slowly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are the data types of the columns you're inserting into? By default SQL Server uses UCS-2 encoding for nchar, ntext and nvarchar column types so it sounds like your problematic data may contain invalid Unicode characters for one of those columns. i.e.: Basic Multilingual Plane characters only, Emoji and other such characters requiring UTF-16 probably won't work.

Comment: The columns I'm trying to insert are all either integers, datetime objects, or strings. There shouldn't be any emoji's and when I look I haven't seen any characters outside the basic latin alphabet and basic integers. And as I noted with fast_execuemany off it loads without error, so I don't think the issue is sql.

Comment: Have you tried comparing some of the good files against some of the errant files at the byte level? e.g.: Use your favorite hex editor (e.g.: Visual Studio Code with the "hexdump for VSCode" extension) to load good/bad files and test for differences in their Byte Order Marks. Are the good files ASCII/ANSI format, the bad ones UTF8? If you change the file encoding to ASCII/ANSI from whatever it currently is can it be imported successfully?

Comment: When I attempt to encode to ASCII I get this error: "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 199314: ordinal not in range(128)"  When I encode it with ANSI, I get the original error. I do believe the one that doesn't run is in UTF8. Or at least I can encode it to UTF8, yet still get the original error.